# How do I pass values from my express middleware function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, express

I am a beginner in Javascript/Node/Express.

I am trying to get some data from the Facebook Graph API and have an Express middleware function as given below.

What I want to achieve is this:-

Get a user authentication token from Facebook - Done
Pass that user authentication token to the middleware function - Done
Retrieve the data and display it on the screen as a graph - Using chart.js for the front end charting, but I'm unable to send this data there.

```
function getFBData(req, res, next){
var impressions = [];
var dates = [];
graph.setAccessToken(req.user.facebook.token);
//graph.get("me/accounts", function(err,res){
// console.log(res);
//});

//var impressions = [];
//var dates = [];
graph.get("{page-id-placeholder}/insights/page_impressions/day",function(err,res){

//console.log(res);
//console.log(res.data[0]);
for(i=0; i<res.data[0].values.length; i++){
setArrayData(impressions, res.data[0].values[i].value);
setArrayData(dates, res.data[0].values[i].end_time);
}

console.log("inside!!");
console.log(impressions);
console.log(dates);

});

function setArrayData(array, value){
console.log("Pushing " + value + "into " + array);
array.push(value);
console.log("Now the array contains " + array);
}

console.log("Impressions = " + impressions);
console.log("Dates = " + dates);
res.locals.FBData = [impressions, dates]
console.log(res.locals.FBData);
return next();

}
```

Now the problem I am facing is that the array is empty at the time of setting in res.locals.FBData

I think I am doing something wrong in basic javascript but not able to pin-point what it is.

Edit:- I am able to see the values being set in the array through the function setArrayData as well as inside the graph.get statement console.log, but the array is empty outside.

My assumption is that the arrays impressions and dates are both global in scope wrt to this function and it should not be reset.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graph.get is asynchronous. You need to do it like this:

```
function getFBData(req, res, next){
    var impressions = [];
    var dates = [];

    graph.setAccessToken(req.user.facebook.token);

    graph.get("{page-id-placeholder}/insights/page_impressions/day",function(err,res){

        for(i=0; i<res.data[0].values.length; i++){
            impressions.push(res.data[0].values[i].value);
            dates.push(res.data[0].values[i].end_time);
        }

        console.log("Impressions = " + impressions);
        console.log("Dates = " + dates);
        res.locals.FBData = [impressions, dates]
        console.log(res.locals.FBData);
        return next();

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
return next();
```

with

```
next();
```

in middlewares the next function helps you to pass data to next middleware.

Comment: I'm not getting the values at this point itself

console.log("Impressions = " + impressions);
console.log("Dates = " + dates);
res.locals.FBData = [impressions, dates]
console.log(res.locals.FBData);